# Crop NSURL / NSString

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nsurl, crop

I got some URL's heading to certain mp3's like:

```
(1) localhost://blablabla/song1.mp3
(2) localhost://blablabla/songwithmorechars.mp3
```

and so on.

How can I crop the URL's to:

```
(1) song1.mp3
(2) songwithmorechars.mp3
```

Need to display the current song my `AVAudioPlayer` is playing in a `UILabel`.

Thanks

**SOLUTION:**

Here's the deal:

```
titleLabel.text = [[[self.audioPlayer.url absoluteString] lastPathComponent] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".mp3" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the substring with the last / (there's a method in ObjC for that!)

```
NSString *sub = [url lastPathComponent];
```

Here's the info for that method:

[NSString lastPathComponent Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `[url lastPathComponent]`, you don't need to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 NSString *lastString = [yourStringName lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *firstURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"localhost://blablabla/song1.mp3"];
NSString *firstString = [firstURL absoluteString];
NSLog(@"Name:%@",[firstString lastPathComponent]);
```

From docs:

[NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/relativePath)

[NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent)